# Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E being intercepted by tmux

Tags: macos, tmux

Unsure when it started happening, but tmux appears to be preventing the normal behavior of Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E. Instead of jumping to the beginning or end of the line, it is printing out the characters themselves, "^A" and "^E". I'm using Alacritty as my terminal, and it works just fine when I am not inside tmux.

**Update:**
After help from a commenter, it appears the issue is not tmux configuration related. The issue presents itself even without the use of a config file. It also can be reproduced using other terminals, so it's not an Alacritty issue either. A coworker of mine is using the same tmux version as I am (2.9a) and is not running into the same issue. Our `stty -a` settings are the same. Any thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: I started `tmux` with the config you provided and it didn't replicate the issue. I'm on Kubuntu though, not macOS. Does the issue occur after starting a new `tmux` server without custom config? (e.g. `tmux -f /dev/null -S foo123`). If it doesn't, try disabling (commenting out) more and more parts of your config, until you identify the culprit. After each change you need to start a new `tmux` server to really tell how the modified config affects things.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion. Surprisingly, the issue does still occur after starting a new tmux server without any custom configuration. I guess this means that something about tmux and Alacritty are not playing nicely with each other? Are you using Alacritty as well on Kubunutu?

Comment: No. I had never heard of it until I read your question.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what was causing this issue. In my `.zshrc` file, I had

```
export EDITOR='vi'
```

For unknown reasons, tmux does not like quotes around the editor name, so

```
export EDITOR=vi
```

works just as well and gets rid of the issue I was having.

Comment: In theory the two lines should have identical effect: the variable with the content `vi`. By examining the variable itself there is no way to tell if it was set using quotes. If this really solved the issue then there must be some peculiarity behind it.

Comment: I also had a very similar issue. The weirdest part is that I use Nix with the exact same config across multiple machines. Only one machine exhibited this behavior, and only inside of tmux. In my regular kitty terminal the commands worked fine. I commented and uncommented lines and eventually the issue went away. I put my config back to exactly the same way it was before, rebuilt and the issue couldn't be reproduced. This is speculation, but I have a gut feeling that it was due to a bad `.zcompdump` in my home directory. Deleting that file might help the next poor soul